# Как нужно использовать url_for для метода get класса-потомка MethodView?

Tags: python, flask

Суть проблемы: Не получается использовать `url_for` для получения URL-а к ресурсу.

Написан класс `UsersAPI`, который унаследован от `flask.views.MethodView`. Для него реализован метод `get`. Класс находится в пакете app.users.

URL к BluePrint-у привязываю так:

```
user_views = UsersAPI.as_view('users')
users.add_url_rule('/', view_func=user_views)
```

Регистрация BluePrint-а такая:

```
from .users import users as users_blueprint
result.register_blueprint(users_blueprint, url_prefix='/users')
```

пытаюсь получить URL к ресурсу таким образом:

```
from flask import url_for
url_for('users.UsersAPI.get')
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

> werkzeug.routing.BuildError: ('users.UsersAPI.get', {}, None)

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока у меня получилось так:
`url_for('users.users')`

Увидел это здесь:

```
>>> app.url_map
Map([<Rule '/auth/users/change-password' (PUT, OPTIONS) -> auth.change_password>,
 <Rule '/auth/users/unregister' (DELETE, OPTIONS) -> auth.unregister_user>,
 <Rule '/auth/users/register' (POST, OPTIONS) -> auth.register_user>,
 <Rule '/executables/upload' (POST, OPTIONS) -> executables.upload_file>,
 <Rule '/users/' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> users.users>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> static>])
```

Для большей наглядности as_view() должен плучать имя view-шки с более наглядным именем, чем 'users'.